# Fold Unfold on click of button in Monaco Editor

Tags: json, monaco-editor

I am using Monaco Editor 0.10.0 in Angular project. I have JSON file loaded on editor with folding as enabled.
I would like to introduce two buttons on my page which will fold/unfold my json code in Monaco Editor. How we can achieve this in Monaco Editor ?

Click here for sample:
[Fold Unfold on click of button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbKDL.gif)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use editor.trigger command to fold/unfold.

HTML Code:

```
    <button (click)="fold()">Fold</button>
    <button (click)="unfold()">Unfold</button>
```

JS Code:

```
  fold(){
         editor.trigger('fold', 'editor.foldAll');
  }
  unfold(){
         editor.trigger('unfold', 'editor.unfoldAll');
  }
```

Comment: how to just fold/unfold the first one?